# How to create a loop to extract data from a .csv file

Tags: loops, csv, python-2.x

I face this issue and can't seem to find a fix except with Scipy or Numpy, both of which I don't wanna use in this case.

From a .csv file, I want to extract the values of the first column :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjMX8.png)

Which I manage to do with the following code :

```
mat_data = open('file.csv')
data_reader = csv.reader(mat_data)
list_data = list(data_reader)
value1=float(list_data[1][0])
value2=float(list_data[2][0])
value3=float(list_data[3][0])
```

I'd now like to create a loop that could be used and create value"i" no matter how many lines long my .csv is.
Any idea?

Comment: `map(lambda x: x[0], data_reader)` should give you a list of the first column

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me !

```
mat_data = open('file.csv')
data_reader = csv.reader(mat_data)
list_data = list(data_reader)

i=0
value=dict()
for i in range(1,len(list_data)):
    value[i]=list_data[i][0]
    print value[i]
```